# Ставится ли в данном предложении запятая перед союзным словом "что" ("что именно")?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Ставится ли в данном предложении запятая перед союзным словом "что"?

"Мне без разницы что именно".

Answer (score 1):

Ставится. И здесь это не союз, а союзное слово.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, исправила. Но есть ли какое-то объяснение? Если, допустим, перед Вами диалог:                                               - Что тебе купить? - спросила Оля.                     - Мне не важно(?) что именно, - ответила я впопыхах.

Comment: Так это сложноподчиненное предложение.

Comment: А вот если, допустим, предложение и заканчивается на словах "что именно", то запятая всё равно ставится?

Comment: Так у вас предложение как раз и заканчивается на словах "что именно". Смотрите, когда запятая в сложноподчиненном предложении в похожих случаях НЕ ставится:
...
*в) если придаточное предложение состоит из одного только союзного слова (относительного местоимения или наречия), например: Меня упрекают, но не знаю в чём; Уходя, он обещал скоро вернуться, но не уточнил когда; Мать температуру определяла губами: приложит губы ко лбу и сразу определит сколько.* (Источник: http://rosental-book.ru/punct_xxviii.html#sect107)

Comment: То есть запятая не должна ставиться, если я уберу слово "именно"?

Comment: Да, тогда запятой не будет.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо! Значит, я перепутала, думая, якобы запятая всё равно не ставится, если в придаточной части присутствует ещё что-то, кроме союзного слова.